# Install QGIS on Debian testing (Trixie)

Tags: debian, qgis, apt

Following the [installation page of QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) for Debian/Ubuntu, it appears that QGIS supports either the stable release of Debian (currently Debian 12 *Bookworm*), or the unstable branch of Debian (*sid*). But the current testing branch (Debian 13 *Trixie*) is not mentioned.

I tried those two options by changing the codename in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources` file.

**The first one, using bookworm:**

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: bookworm
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

But when I try `apt install qgis`, I get the `You have held broken packages` error, as it can't find the `libgdal32` package.

**The second one, using sid:**

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: sid
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

I also get the error but this time for `libspatialite7` and `qtbase-abi-5-15-8`.

Is there any way to install QGIS on Debian testing as of today?